# Unable to Update View Via UI

Tags: views

This is not an issue of a broken handlers or missing fields.

I cannot update any existing or new views on my site. For example, if I try to add a field, nothing happens after I click apply. The field is not added, but the view reminds me to save my changes. [This screenshot demonstrates what happens](https://i.imgur.com/WunbyrE.gifv).

A few things to note:

- Disabling views caching and javascript does not work.
- Disabling overlay does not work.
- I'm not getting any memory limit issues.
- Exporting the view and re-uploading it does not work
- I am running 7.x-3.11

Comment: PHP errors? Go to /admin/config/development/logging and specify [X] All messages. Also, enable dblog, try to make the change again, then view /admin/reports/dblog - anything showing up?

Comment: @jonpeck thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, I'm seeing nothing in the watchdog or server logs.

Comment: Do you have jQuery update installed? If so, go to the config for it and change the admin theme jQuery version to the one included with core. Although if disabling js doesn't fix it that's probably not the problem

Comment: @Clive I tried jQuery update, and even set the default theme to Bartik, but no luck.

Comment: @StephenMartin Can you please see what it is showing in browser console?

Comment: @SumitMadan, I get this this. `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: Hmm!!! It doesn't seems related to this. Are you checking this at view page while updating view field?

Comment: @SumitMadan yeah, this appears when I add the field.

Comment: Are you using updated version of views. If not try to update and check.

Comment: @SumitMadan, yes I am using the newest release. I even removed views and installed again.